# android internals

Tags: android

I just need a little help in my project. Can anyone tell how does android loads all the apps on the device while booting up. Where does it read the apk's retrieves information about the app like the icons, name and finally displays onto the device.

I went through packagemanager->applicationpackagemanager->Ipackagemanager.aidl->packagemanagerservice->settings.java but i couldnot figure out how does android pulls information from apk and how does it loads on booting up.

It would be realy great if somebody could help.

Answer (score 3):

no idea where that exactly happens but AFAIK:

During boot: Android goes through `/data/apps/*.apk`, extracts / reads the `AndroidManifest.xml` and saves some info (e.g. `/data/system/packages.list` and `packages.xml`)

Package (`.apk`) parsing should be done by [PackageParser.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java#PackageParser)

The list of apps is probably read from one of those lists when you open the apps drawer and cached in memory. Icons are extracted on demand and also cached. The icons /apps you see in Launcher are stored somewhere else.